# Java client sends a partial message to server although shows as a full message

Tags: java, tcpclient

I have a client written in Java and a server written in C++. The client is supposed to send a message like this "MESSAGE|1|2|3|4|5" every 5 seconds upon receiving the response from server.

Starts connection:

```
private Socket socket = null;
private DataInputStream input = null;
private DataOutputStream output = null;
private BufferedReader br = null;
private Timer timer;

public void start() 
{
    int timerRate = 5;

    try
    {
        int refreshRate = Integer.parseInt(appSingleton.getRefreshRateShared());
        timerRate = refreshRate;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        LOGGER.addLogError("Error converting refresh rate: "+e);
    }

    try
    {
        // Create socket and streams
        socket = new Socket(appSingleton.getIpAddressFullShared(), appSingleton.getIpPortShared());
        input = new DataInputStream( socket.getInputStream());
        output = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream());

        // Start Timer thread
        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                // Create new TCP connection if the map is not currently updating
                if(isMapUpdating == false)
                {
                    isMapUpdating = true;

                    communicateWithServer();
                }
            }
        }, 0, timerRate, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        cancelConnection();
    }

    catch (EOFException e)
    {
        cancelConnection();
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        cancelConnection();
    }
}

public void communicateWithServer()
{
    // Create a message to the server
    String messageToServer = makeMessageToServer(); 
    String messageFromServer = connectToClient(messageToServer);

    // Read the message and update panel on the main thread
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
    {
        messageReceived(messageFromServer);
    });
}

public String connectToClient(String messageToServer)
{
    String data = "";
    // Message from the server that should terminate TCP connection
    String  terminator = "END_DATA";

    try 
    {
        //Send message to the server
        output = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream());
        output.writeBytes(messageToServer);

        System.out.println("OUTPUT LENGTH: "+output.size());

        //Read Response
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s = "";
        int value;

        // Process the message from the server and add to the StringBuilder
        while((value = br.read()) != -1) 
        {
            // converts int to character
            char c = (char)value;

            sb.append(c);

            if(sb.toString().contains(terminator))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        // Create the final string
        data = sb.toString();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        cancelConnection();
        data = "ERROR";
    }

    return data;
}

private void messageReceived(String message)
{
    // Processing data from server and displaying values on Main Thread

    // Map finished updating when data is processed
    isMapUpdating = false;
}
```

The server gets the message from the client, converts it to an array, and then processes the data further on. The first message is sent just fine. However, on the second message, the server crashes. I checked what is being sent to the server, and it turns out that the messages are like this:

"MESSAGE|1|2|3|4|5"

"M"

"ESSAGE|1|2|3|4|5"

So, the server crashes on the second received message since it cannot split it into arrays.

When I check the DataOutputStream, it always shows me the correct size.

If someone has an idea how to fix it, this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are going to write networking software, both sides need to be able to handle that data may be fragmented and arrive piece by piece; you will normally not be in full control over this.

To lessen the risk, though, flush the output stream after writing to it:

```
    output = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream());
    output.writeBytes(messageToServer);
    output.flush();
```

It tells the stream to write buffered data to the next layer.

Comment: I have changed the server and it does not crash now. However, it does continue to show partial messages, so it is not working as it should. Unfortunately, adding `flush()` does not help either. Now, I wonder if the culprit may be associated with the threading...